# Magento 2 : Banner full width

Tags: magento2

In my home page having two banners.How to give give second banner to full width wrt to reference block

```
    <referenceContainer name="content.bottom">
      <block class="some name">
      <action method="setSliderId">
       <argument name="sliderId" xsi:type="string">2</argument>
     </action>
       </block>
    </referenceContainer>
```

How to add full width of banner in content

Comment: it is css work! simply set `width:100%`  it set full width, relative to the parant element width.

Comment: no image clarity is not coming good,we are adding that image through extension